# How to create simple product to attribute option value in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product

I created my own attribute set in magento, let say "MyAttribSet" with a large number of option values.
How can I retrieve these values and assign/create to each one a simple product programatically?
[I found code sample here, but I'm missing the latter part with option values:](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/comment-page-1/#comment-22380)

I'm using Magento version is 1.5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
             ->getAttribute('catalog_product', '955');
    foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option){

  //here comes the code sample (see link before)
                  .
                  .
                  .
  $product->setMyCustomAttribute($option['value']);
}
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted, it is allowed and even suggested by stackoverflow rules.